# Why can't I see my published Roblox game?

Tags: roblox

I went to Roblox Studios, clicked File, clicked Upload To Roblox As, filled out the info and submitted.  It said I successfully uploaded, but when I got to play I don't see my game, and I don't see it it my creations list.

Comment: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/resources/cc-summer-2019/save-and-publish

Answer (score 1):

Go to the developer tab(roblox.com/develop), find your game BUT DON’T CLICK IT YET. You are going to click the blue text next to (start place:). Click the ... icon, then click add to profile. You will see this on your profile.